# Can I install Ubuntu in uefi if I installed windows 10 in legacy?

Tags: uefi

I'm new to Linux and want to install Ubuntu in uefi mode (no dual mode). However I had windows currently installed in legacy mode. So will I encounter any problem if I switch boot mode to uefi? I don't plan on keeping windows and would like to remove all traces of it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can install any OS in (u)efi or legacy regardless of how the current OS was installed.

Heck, you can even have a system installed as legacy and as (u)efi but that would require you to choose from bios (so no automatic switching during boot) what system you want to boot if you need to switch.

Needless to say (I hope) that it is best to install all OS on 1 system with the same boot procedure, so either all legacy or all (u)efi.

> So will I encounter any problem if I switch boot mode to uefi?

Generally: no. Do remove legacy installed OS during installation and make sure you follow the 1st (u)efi install procedures: you need to create your (u)efi partition yourself. Manual method: [How to prepare a disk on an EFI based PC for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu)  though I expect the installer to do it correctly too nowadays.